# R - repeating the same lines of code for different columns in a imported CSV file

Tags: r, loops, csv, import

I am new to R and I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to loop a few lines of code for different columns of a CSV file automatically. The code I have so far is this:

```
q1 <- VectorSource(hcsv$one)
q1 <- q1[1:32]
frequencyQ1 <- sort(table(q1), decreasing = TRUE)
write.csv(frequencyQ1, "frequencyQ1.csv")
```

and I would like to repeat this twenty times while also changing the name of written file each time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

```
for (i in 1:20){
  q1 <- VectorSource(hcsv[,i])
  q1 <- q1[1:32]
  frequencyQ1 <- sort(table(q1), decreasing = TRUE)
  write.csv(frequencyQ1, paste("frequencyQ",i,".csv",sep=""))
}
```